# ClamTk found Trojan.Generic-6888382 in Javascript directory

Tags: security, malware, trojan

TROJAN IN Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - JAVA SCRIPT
I run ClamTK and it finds Trojan.Generic-6888382 in usr/share/javascript/jquery-ui.min
I delete it, but then it's there again. I quarantine it, but it's there again.
I go to the directory, but don't have the access rights to delete it.
Please can anyone tell me how to remove this trojan, either by sudo script, or AV process?
Many thanks.
[image: Screenshot of the ClamTk trojan description]

Comment: First of all, you should send that file to the `clamav` developers through their site https://www.clamav.net, in order for them to verify that this is not a false positive. If they do verify the findings, they will probably tell you how to get rid of it.

Comment: Thank you... I've "Made it so".

Answer (score 0):

Summary of problem - ClamTk found the trojan but didn't delete it and I didn't have the access rights to delete the file, or directory. (I followed advice and reported the issue to ClamNet)

I then tried to reinstall Ubuntu and messed up my pen drive containing the Ubuntu ISO, and searched for it's name 'uui' in the file system. Happily, this search resulted in the prompt "Do I want to run 'file system' as Boot Administrator?"
I answered "Yes", entered my password and deleted the directories containing the trojan.
I rebooted the laptop and ran ClamTk again and the trojan had not reappeared.
So.... was I "feeling lucky, punk?".... the answer was "Yes!"

So the solution if ClamTk finds malware, but doesn't delete it is:
 - report it to Clam.net
 - run file system as Boot Admin and delete the malware files or containing directory.